# Add async in a non-async interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a legacy .NET Framework application that’s been running for a decade.

There is an interface:

```
interface IService
{
   void Run();
}
```

And this interface is implemented in many existing classes. There is a central manager that picks up all classes implementing `IService` and calls the `Run()` method on each class. (This code is already available and runs as expected).

Now, I want to add one more class that implements this same `IService`, but I want `Run()` to be an `async Task` instead of a `void`, as I am dealing with API calls in this new class. I don't want to disturb the existing functionality of how the central manager works.

Comment: Even if you could, how would you ensure the code that runs the `Run` method does it as an async method?

Comment: If the only class which is going to use an `async` version of `Run` is this new class, why not just create a new Interface? Name it something like `IServiceAsync` and have a method with signature `async Task` called `RunAsync`?? I think what the previous comment is implying, is that if you could change the signature of `Run` in your interface, there's no gaurantee it would run async as the classes implementing the interface would have to define the behavior.

Comment: @gunr2171 The central manager picks up each class one by one initially and runs them in separate threads. And the ```Run()``` class itself at the end of the code until its is commanded to stop

Comment: @RyanWilson I did think about that, but trying to fit in the existing code, because the central manager then does lots of logs and reports etc

Comment: Why not make your manager call Task.Run(()=>implementor.Run());

Comment: Question: Do you want to introduce asynchronous functionality because it's critical to the performance of your application? Or do you only want to do it to maintain compatibility with an underlying API (such as `HttpClient`) that exposes asynchronous methods itself? The answer to that question will significantly impact the best approach to addressing this problem, and is at the heart of the difference between [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71756429/3025856) and [@Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71756390/3025856) below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change your interface to (optionally) support asynchronous calls in a way that maintains backward compatibility—and that’s a good thing.

#### Explanation

Remember, the entire purpose of an interface is to guarantee that all callers can interact with a concrete implementation of that interface without knowing anything about the concrete type itself. Implementing a method as `async` changes that method’s signature—i.e., by returning a `Task<>` and potentially expecting an `await` keyword, depending on how it’s called—and, therefore, breaks the interface. You can change the signature, but by definition that breaks backward compatibility with the existing interface.

#### Options

Given this, there are three textbook solutions to this problem:

1. Handle the asynchronous calls within your existing synchronous interface, as suggested in [@Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71756390/3025856). This maintains backwards compatibility, but eliminates the benefits of asynchronous calls.
2. Change the interface to use `async`, thus requiring all implementations to be updated. This is the most invasive approach, and may not be practical if you don't own all implementations.
3. Create a new `async` version of your interface (e.g., `IServiceAsync`) which is used by implementations and callers requiring asynchronous functionality, as suggested in [@Ryan Wilson’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755983/add-async-in-a-non-async-interfaces/71756429#comment126808919_71755983).

If your priority is exclusively backward compatibility with existing code, and not the performance benefits of asynchronous processing, you should take the first option.

Assuming you *want* the performance benefits of asynchronous calls, however, the last option makes the most sense given that you are working with legacy code; that will be especially true if you don’t own all of the implementations.

The rest of this answer will assume the third option.

#### Base Interface

If appropriate, your synchronous and asynchronous interfaces can derive from a common interface which shares any non-`async` methods, thus allowing them to be used interchangeably in those scenarios. This is useful if you have code that doesn’t rely on any of the implicated `async` methods. Your question doesn't suggest that, but I'm assuming your interface may be more involved than what's included here.

#### Central Manager

Your central manager will need to be updated to look for both `IService` and `IServiceAsync`, and conditionally call e.g., `RunAsync()` on the latter. Just make sure you’re truly taking advantage of the asynchronous capabilities in that case (e.g., by adding these to a task queue and processing tasks as they complete). Otherwise, you won't gain any performance benefits from the asynchronous interface.

#### Impact

I recognize that your objective was to avoid updating your central manager. Unfortunately, though, there’s no way to accomplish this while *also* taking advantage of any asynchronous processing desired for the API call.

Comment: The `async` and `await` keywords are just an imitation detail.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Yes, for sure. I assumed that since the task-based asynchronous pattern is the recommended and most common implementation. But, regardless of which asynchronous pattern you use, asynchronous methods change the signature and, thus, the interface. I think that's the most important point here.

Comment: Quite true and I think this is a good answer in general but you phrase it as making the interface `async` which is a bit awkward. Also the synchronous interface could be wrapped in an asynchronous adapter. Overall though, plus one

Comment: @JeremyCaney my intention is to make use of both sync and async functionalities. As you said, use sync as usual and make use of async if possible (for performance improvement and newer APIs will have async most of the time). I had thought of adding sync to async to the central manager, but I wanted to know if I have any other better options. You have broken down my problems very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your new async functionality in a non-async way.

```
class AsyncService : IService
{
    public void Run()
    {
        myasyncFunction().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also need a `ConfigureAwait(false)` so that continuations don't have to run back in the context which is blocked in the `GetResult()` call?

Comment: Depends on if it's .net core or framework or asp.  It probably wouldn't harm in any case.

Comment: This is a good alternative for maintaining backward compatibility with the existing interface and the central manager. But, of course, it defeats the purpose of using asynchronous calls in the first place. That might be acceptable to the OP if the goal is just to maintain compatibility with e.g. `HttpClient.ReadAsStringAsync()` (or some other underlying asynchronous call). If the goal is to mitigate the performance impact of multiple expensive API calls, however, they'll obviously need to introduce support for async calls into the central manager.

Comment: This *does* cause problems and deadlocks so it's considered an antipattern. Stephen Toub explained why [as far back as 2012](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). This code will freeze threadpool threads

Comment: I believe using .Result is what Stephen explained as the anti-pattern, but elsewhere he mentions that the GetAwaiter/GetResult pattern is a workaround for this edge case.  I agree that the whole project should be async all the way down, but sometimes that's just not possible.

Comment: The only difference between `.GetAwaiter().GerResult()` and `.Result` is exception unwrapping. The calling thread is blocked one way or another.